# Autoscaling with AWS instances using Ansible-Pull with Master and slave Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-pull

I am working with AWS instances currently and want to transfer all the configuration that is currently running on AWS master node to the multiple AWS slave nodes with Ansible only. Slave nodes may be 2 or 3 or may be more. Is it possible with the `ansible-pull` model to automatically scale the AWS instance when the "Utilization" of the slave node goes down or up?

How can I assign the AWS Cluster of the Nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it is not a direct answer, in the case of configuring auto-scale, I use **Bootstrap Pattern**.

Put the secret key for the git repository and ansible-vault on S3 (authenticated by IAM role of instance), and put the playbooks on git repository.

User Data of EC2 instance is `pip install ansible`, `get secret key from S3`, `get playbook from git repository` and `execute ansible-playbook`.

If there are some role of EC2 instance, you can split S3 directory and git path.

Self bootstrap mechanism make the auto-scale process more simple.

**Update01: Samples**

EC2 User Data Sample (not yet tested, as an image):

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y
pip install -y ansible

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/web/git_secret_key /root/.ssh/git_secret_key
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/git_secret_key

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/web/config /root/.ssh/config
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/web/ansible_vault_secret_key /root/ansible_vault_secret_key

git clone git://github.com/foo/playbook.git

ansible-playbook -i playbook/inventory/web playbook/web.yml --vault-password-file /root/ansible_vault_secret_key
```

s3://mybucket/web/config Sample:

```
Host github-bootstrap
  User git
  Port 22
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/git_secret_key
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

**Update02: Most simple ver. (without S3/ansible-vault)**

EC2 User Data Sample (not yet tested, as an image):

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y
pip install -y ansible

echo "YOUR GIT SECRET KEY" > /root/.ssh/git_secret_key
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/git_secret_key

cat << EOT > /root/.ssh/config
Host github-bootstrap
  User git
  Port 22
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/git_secret_key
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
EOT
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config

git clone git://github.com/foo/playbook.git

ansible-playbook -i playbook/inventory/web playbook/web.yml
```

Comment: This looks like working to me. Is it mandatory to create the snapshot on S3 and work with the Ansible-vault ?

Comment: If your playbook has no secret data, you don't have to use ansible-vault and secret key for this. And, if your git repository is in secure, you don't have to put secret key of git repository on S3. In most simple case, you don't have to use S3.

I think snapshot is unnecessary in all cases, but do you need copy the state of master node to slave? If you want to copy the state of master node to slave, it will need transfer process or snapshot.

Comment: I have the private github repository in which I have the files which contains basic configurations that I need to apply on slaves. So, will the AWS Slave automatically catch the files or assigns the config from the github repos when new slave instance comes up with auto scaling facility (Ansible Pull)  ? or do I need to set the cron job for those ?

Comment: Please see updated samples. AWS Slaves execute self `git clone` by User Data of EC2 settings for catching configurations.

Comment: Is this done automatically ? or Do I need to run those shell script everytime whenever the new instance comes up ?. If yes then, there is no reason for ansible-pull..

Comment: It is automatically done. "User Data" of EC2 is fired at booting new instance.

Comment: There is User Data in Launch Configuration. http://img.svbtle.com/myezzobsm3zmg.png

Comment: What would be the possible change if I don't want to use the Ansible-vault and AWS S3. ?.. I just want to fetch file from the github repository only and apply the autoscaling.

Comment: Please see Update02. The secret key and config files are embedded in User Data.

Comment: Awesome...Will it do the autoscaling on AWS without S3 or is it must ?

Comment: It do the auto scaling on AWS without S3. S3 and ansible-vault provide more secure mechanism, but there are not needed for core mechanism of auto scaling.

Comment: I actually created launch configuration with ec2_lc module and also done load balancing with ec2_elb_lb module. The thing is I have pushed the configuration on to the ansible nodes. With Ansible-pull, how can I assign those shell script for user-data using Ansible-script or with any modules ?

Comment: Do you use ansible for "creating structure (A)" and "setup instance (B)"? I think this thread is about (B). And It seems that the question above is about (A). I usually use CloudFormation or terraform for (A). But if you want to use ansible for (A), you can write script of Update02 in user_data of ec2_lc module. NOTE: In this case (for B), you don't have to use ansible-pull. Just write like as a Update02 ('ansible-playbook -i xxx yyy.yml').

Comment: I created module for autoscaling and load balancing. What I want is, when new instance comes up, it will automatically load all the config for my github repo. to that new instance and depending on the utilization it is goes some percent below then it will also needs to be terminated. If someone changes something in the github repo then those config automatically apply to the instances without running the .yml file again. Is that possible ?.I know Ansible tower is the best alternative, can we do with the scripts ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply the modified configuration to the existing terminated instance (not a new instance) ? How about using init.d scripts same as User Data ? But, it will pull and rerun the .yml file again at the booting process (because of ansible has idempotency, there is no problem). I seem it is difficult that the existing instance follows modified configuration without the .yml file.